# Calling a `scala.Function1[_root_.scala.Predef.String, scala.Any]` from within Java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I am currently working on a Java project that has to use another project written in Scala. My question is a very simple one: How can I call a `scala.Function1[_root_.scala.Predef.String, scala.Any]` from within my Java application?

The method I need to call is this:

`var onMessageCb : scala.Function1[_root_.scala.Predef.String, scala.Any] = { /* compiled code */ }`

This is how I am trying to call this function (in Java):

```
public void onMessage(String message) {
  onMessageCb(message);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It works when calling it like this: `onMessageCb().apply(message);`.